# Can´t get the logout session from facebook to work

Tags: php, html, facebook, codeigniter, sdk

i tried to use the facebook login in my project.  For this i use the PHP SDK in codeigniter..

all works and i can do the login and retrieve data to my page.

But i can´t understand why the logout doesn´t work, because when i click on the logout link nothing happend.

i have search a lot of things in the internet and tried too.

I don´t know what do now .. hope someone can help me with this.

here is my code:

model/Facebook_model

```
<?php
class Facebook_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $config = array(
                        'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        'fileUpload' => true, // Indicates if the CURL based @ syntax for file uploads is enabled.
                        );

        $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
        //
        // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
        // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
        // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
        $profile = null;
        if($user)
        {
            try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }

        $fb_data = array(
                        'me' => $profile,
                        'uid' => $user,
                        'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                            array(
                                'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream', // app permissions
                                //'redirect_uri' => site_url('home') // URL where you want to redirect your users after a successful login
                                'redirect_uri' => base_url()
                            )
                        ),
                        'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),                     
                    );

    }
}
```

controller/mycontroller.php (i have a search function for other functionality)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Concertos extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('Facebook_model');
    }
function topsecret()
    {
        $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data');

        if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me']))
        {
            redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array(
                        'fb_data' => $fb_data,
                        );

            $this->load->view('home', $data);
        }
    }

public function search($location)
    {
$fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data');
$data ['fb_data'] = $fb_data;

            $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
```

view/home.php

```
  <?php 

        if(!$fb_data['me']): ?>
        Please login with your FB account: <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['loginUrl']; ?>">login</a>
        <!-- Or you can use XFBML -->
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="100" data-max-rows="1" data-scope="email,user_birthday,publish_stream"></div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb_data['uid']; ?>/picture" alt="" class="pic" />
        <p>Hi <?php echo $fb_data['me']['name']; ?>,<br />
         <a href="<?php echo $fb_data['logoutUrl']; ?>">logout</a></p>
        <?php endif; 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating session, when you logout you need to destroy it in you logout function. Then you need to link to this function.

```
function logout()
{
     $this->CI->session->sess_destroy();
     // do more thing you want to do such as redirect
}
```

Comment: i have tried this code... i have insert it into the controller.. and in the Facebook_model put a redirect url to call this function, but still nothing happend..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything is wrong. Do you know that getLogoutUrl will logout the user from facebook.com. So if want to logout user from only app, I think it need some other native code.